# Zend decorators: How can I use jquery-ui classes on my forms?

Tags: jquery-ui, zend-framework, zend-form, zendx

I create a form in a Zend Framework using jquery:

```
    class Contact_Form_Contact extends ZendX_JQuery_Form {

  public function init() {
        /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
        //create new element
        $name = $this->createElement('text', 'name');
        //element options
        $name->setLabel("Enter your name:");
        $name->setRequired(TRUE);
        $name->setAttrib('size', 40);
        //add element to the form

        $this->addElement($name);
        .....
```

If request fails setRequired enables class=errors,

How to override it to "`ui-state-error my-clean`"?

Arman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of overwriting decorators, you can set decorator options that way:

```
$element->getDecorator('Errors')->setOption('class', 'ui-state-error my-clean')
```

Comment: nice this solution is also useful.

Answer (score 2):

After seriously reading the blogs of Zend I found that it is very easy to do that with decorator:

```
  $this->setElementDecorators(array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Label',
        array('Errors', array('class'=>'ui-state-error'))
    ));
```